# Magento 2 Rest API - How to add custom comment option to Cart Item

Tags: magento2.2, cart, rest-api

I am using Magento 2 default quoteCartItem Rest APIs to add and update items in cart.

I want to add custom comment option in cart.
Any custom module to send comment using rest API.
I'm new in magento 2, not too familiar with technical keywords. Hope I explained this question properly.